# Android - DialogPreferenec with one button only

Tags: android-layout, android-preferences, android

By default, DialogPreference has two buttons - OK and Cancel.
I want to leave only the OK button and remove the cancel button - how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#alerts

You should only need the setPositiveButton attibute.

Comment: I don't need an alert but a DialogPreferene

Comment: I caught that after I posted then couldn't get back in to update. I see your difficulty. Not much seems to be available on customizing the buttons. If I find anything, I'll send it on.

Comment: It looks like you may have to subclass it to create your own. I've never done that, but I found a good example to start with. Hope it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505845/concise-way-of-writing-new-dialogpreference-classes

Answer (score 3):

You can easily remove the cancel button or okey button just set the `setNegativeButtonText(null);` for cancel and `setPositiveButtonText(null);` for okey.