# Custom PreferenceScreen in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have a standard preference page in my app. But from this preference page i want the user to be able to navigate to an other PreferenceScreen with a custom layout, when user presses "Manage Favorits.

This is the custom layout i have in mind:

[image]

Is it possible to use custom layout on "sub-preference-screens"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can launch a separate `activity` using `intent`.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/your_title"
    android:summary="@string/your_string">

        <intent android:targetClass="your.package.YourClass"
            android:targetPackage="your.package" />
    </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

As long as you want to specify your own layout you would need to extend `Preference` class.

Use `setLayoutResource()` to define your layout in your constructor. Constructor needs to be

```
public YourClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
    }
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505845/concise-way-of-writing-new-dialogpreference-classes).