# Is there a simple way to customize the layout of an activity subclassing PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android

I was wondering is there is an easy way to customize the look and feel of a prefs activity like below. Nothing fancy, just things like text size and bacground color

```
public class ActivityPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.prefsTitle);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668293/custom-preferencescreen-in-preferencescreen i think this one has your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way like this, in AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:name=".ActivityPreferences" />
```

or, u can refer to ur own style here.