# Persist multiple values from a DialogPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am having difficulty persisting multiple values from a dialog preference. I have a DialogPreference which shows two time pickers, and I would like the time values from each picker persisted (shown below as startTime and endTime). However, my code is returning only the DefValue from my DialogPreference, and I do not understand why these values are not persisting....Thanks for your help. Code is below:

```
public class TimePickerPreference extends DialogPreference implements
    TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener {
private String startTime;
private String endTime;


private String defaultValue;
public TimePickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

public TimePickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    setPersistent(true);
}

@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
   layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    TextView tvStart = new TextView(getContext());
    TimePicker tp = new TimePicker(getContext());
    TextView tvEnd = new TextView(getContext());
    TimePicker tp2 = new TimePicker(getContext());

    tvStart.setText("From:");
    tvEnd.setText("To:");
    tvStart.setTextSize(14);
    tvEnd.setTextSize(14);

    tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);

    int h = getHour();
    int m = getMinute();
    if (h >= 0 && m >= 0) {
        tp.setCurrentHour(h);
        tp.setCurrentMinute(m);
    }

    tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final long starttime = (minute * 60 + hourOfDay * 60 * 60) * 1000;
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            startTime = format.format(starttime);
            persistString(startTime);

        }
    });
    tp2.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final long endtime = (minute * 60 + hourOfDay * 60 * 60) * 1000;
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            endTime = format.format(endtime);
            persistString(endTime);
        }
    });
    layout.addView(tvStart);
    layout.addView(tp);
    layout.addView(tvEnd);
    layout.addView(tp2);
    return layout;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to your question is here: [Concise way of writing new DialogPreference classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505845/concise-way-of-writing-new-dialogpreference-classes)

I think there are 2 important bugs here based on that link, first the `setPersistent(boolean)` should be false, and second is that you need to use `getEditor()` to store multiple `SharedPreferences` in the `DialogPreference`.