# How to attach OnClickListener to a button in a custom preference layout?

Tags: android, layout, preferences

I have a preference screen that is populated with items from a database.  I have this working by creating my own `PreferenceActivity`.  In the activity I create `DialogPreference` items and add them to my `PreferenceCategory` To style to preference item on the screen I use a custom layout and apply it using `setLayoutResource(R.layout.custom_pref_row)`

This basically adds an `ImageButton` to the view aligned to the right of the layout.   This all works fine and my preference screen shows the custom view with the button.   My question is how do I attach a click listener to the button in the custom view?  I was not able to find a way to get at `View` for the row from the `PreferenceActivity`.   If my items were not created dynamically I might be able to do this all from XML and then reference the id or the button, but I can do that because I am creating the list dynamically.

Any suggestions on how to get a handle on the `ImageButton` for each item?  In the end I want to configure the button to launch a delete confirmation dialog.

R.layout.custom_pref_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:maxLines="2" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pref_delete_station" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_trash_can" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@null"></ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Related part of my PreferenceActivity:

```
DialogPreference diaPref;
for (Station mStation : sList) {
        diaPref = new StationEditor(this.getPreferenceScreen().getContext(), null, this, mStation);
        diaPref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.custom_pref_row);
        diaPref.setTitle(mStation.getName());
        diaPref.setKey(STATION_PREFIX + mStation.getId());

        // add new preference
        stationTypesCategory.addPreference(diaPref);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Chopin got me thinking in a different direction.  I did not realize that the `Preference` object is also responsible for how its selector appears in a Preference screen.

The setLayoutResouce() function sets the resource for the Dialog itself not the row seen in a Preference screen.  This was confusing and I was incorrectly trying to use this in the preference screen to adjust the selector layout there.

The solution is to override `onCreateView` and return a custom layout there.  To me this is counterintuitive because that method usually controls the final view in most other situations.

I alraedy subclassed my `Preference (DialogPreference)` so all I had to do was add the following...

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView (ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferences_station_list_row, null);
    ((ImageButton) customRow.findViewById(R.id.pref_delete_station)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Log.i("c","clicked");
        }
    });

    customRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(null);
        }
    });
    customRow.setClickable(true);
    return customRow;
}
```

One problem I ran into was that at first the row itself was no longer clickable but the button was. I had to add a listener on the whole view and manually call `ShowDialog().`  The only thing missing now is that when clicked from the Preference screen the item no longer shows a highlight.  Any idea what styles I should apply so the list shows the highlight like it normally does?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `DialogPreference` and override the `onBindDialogView(View view)`. Inside this method you can do:

```
@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {

    ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pref_delete_station)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    super.onBindDialogView(view);
}
```

Your sublcass of `DialogPreference` can hold any state/value related to the item it represents.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505845/concise-way-of-writing-new-dialogpreference-classes) about general guidelines to extend `DialogPreference`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I already subclass DialogPreference this should be easy to implement.  I'll give it a try.  Thank you.

Comment: This is not a viable solution.  I am **not** looking to access a button on the `DialogPreference` view.  I am trying to get the button that is part of the preference screen that launches the Dialog.

Comment: Chopin, you got me thinking in the right direction.  Right idea but wrong function.  I needed to override `onCreateView` instead.  There were a few gotchas.  I cant answer my own question for another 4 hours, but I will post the complete solution when I can.

Comment: That is exactly what I was going to suggest! It had to exist some sort of event that you can override to catch the inflation process. I'm glad at least I've triggered your imagination :)