# EditTextPreference With Button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want put a button on android edittextpreference. 
I create a custom editextpreference:

```
public class EditTextPreferenceWithButton extends EditTextPreference {

    private Context context;

    public EditTextPreferenceWithButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context=context;
      }

      public EditTextPreferenceWithButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context=context;
      }

      public EditTextPreferenceWithButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
      }



      @Override
        protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
            super.onBindDialogView(view);



           view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



            final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)editText.getParent();

            Button button = new Button(context);


            vg.addView(button,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        }
}
```

In this way the button is show below the edit text, but I want it is next the edittext like this:

|EditText|  |Button|

Please help me!
Thank you

Comment: you want an edittext with a button on the right that you will add them on a dialog?

Comment: yes. in the dialog that is show when you click on edittextpreference row.

Comment: see my answer, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a subclass of `DialogPreference`.

```
class EditTextDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    //Layout Fields
    private final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
    private final EditText editText = new EditText(this.getContext());
    private final Button button = new Button(this.getContext());


    //Called when addPreferencesFromResource() is called. Initializes basic paramaters
    public EditTextDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPersistent(true);
        button.setText("Button");
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    }

    //Create the Dialog view
    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        layout.addView(editText);
        layout.addView(button);
        return parentLayout;
    }

    //Attach persisted values to Dialog
    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
        editText.setText(getPersistedString("EditText"), TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
    }

    //persist values and disassemble views
    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveresult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveresult);
        if (positiveresult && shouldPersist()) {
            persistString(editText.getText().toString());
        }

        ((ViewGroup) editText.getParent()).removeView(editText);
        ((ViewGroup) button.getParent()).removeView(button);
        ((ViewGroup) layout.getParent()).removeView(layout);

        notifyChanged();
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you're going to persist the value in the `EditText` and I'm leaving the action of the button up to you. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805325/1210260) for more information on the in's and out's of extending `DialogPreference`.

In order to get the key into the `SharedPreferences`, put the following in your XML:

```
<com.yourpackage.EditTextDialogPreference
    android:key="Your Key"
    android:persistent="true"/>
```

Comment: @user As K_Anas said, when your problem is solved, remember to mark an answer as accepted. This really helps other people who come along later with a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, all work fine but when I call addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences) it dont persit the value.

Comment: What are you getting back? Is the preference key valid, and there's just a blank string? Or is there no key at all?

Comment: how can i get click event on that button in my preferencesActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a more concrete class based on @gobernador answer but using `RelativeLayout`:

```
class EditTextDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    //Layout Fields
    private final RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
    private final EditText editText = new EditText(this.getContext());
    private final Button button = new Button(this.getContext());


    //Called when addPreferencesFromResource() is called. Initializes basic paramaters
    public EditTextDialogPreference(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPersistent(true);
        button.setText("Button");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //button action
            }
        });
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

    //Create the Dialog view
    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        layout.addView(editText);
        layout.addView(button);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        return layout;
    }

    //Attach persisted values to Dialog
    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
        editText.setText(getPersistedString("EditText"), TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
    }

    //persist values and disassemble views
    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveresult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveresult);
        if (positiveresult && shouldPersist()) {
            String value = editText.getText().toString();
            if (callChangeListener(value))
                persistString(value);
        }

        ((ViewGroup) editText.getParent()).removeView(editText);
        ((ViewGroup) button.getParent()).removeView(button);
        ((ViewGroup) layout.getParent()).removeView(layout);

        notifyChanged();
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        editText.setText(value);
    }
}
```