# click event on button of custom DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, sharedpreferences

I have created custom Preference dialog from answer of  [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286544/edittextpreference-with-button)

Now I want click event on that button in my `ActivityPreferenceScreen` activity class.
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: I have mentioned that i am using same class which is in link. I just want to add click event on that button  from another class/acitivity. this doesn't incorporate any other specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following attribute in your `Activity`:

```
 OnClickListener prefButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Log.v("Btn", "Clicked");
    }
};
```

In the place you instanciate the `EditTextPreferenceWithButton` class, add this code:

```
editTextPreferenceWithButton.attachButtonListener(prefButtonListener);
```

And then, add following in your `EditTextPreferenceWithButton` class :

```
    public void attachButtonListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        this.button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is causing crash for my application. Logs i have added in edit of my question.